# Grid convergence in ArcGIS Desktop gives conflicting values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I calculated the grid convergence of a feature in ArcGIS (using geographic rotation and none coordinate system). The returned value is negative, which is conflicting to my understanding.

The easting of the calculated location is 570000m, east of central meridian -117, northern hemisphere. My understanding about grid convergence is any position east of central meridian should be positive.

How ArcGIS gave a negative grid convergence value?